# R get names of arguments to a function

Tags: r, function, names

How can I get the names of all the arguments to a function?

```
func = function(a,b,c,d,e){
  return(NULL)
}
```

For the function above, I want to obtain `c('a','b','c','d','e')`, by passing the name of the function (ie `'func'`) to some other function which returns a character vector of the names of the arguments.

Something like this (which doesn't work):

```
args(get('func'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is:

```
names(formals(get("func")))
```